# Can you get away with only completing a third of this puzzle?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I don't have an easy way to test this myself, so I figured I'd ask in case someone else was.

Looking at it from a "trying-to-break-the-game" point of view, the rotating bridge puzzle of the Isle of Songs seems like you can only move the outermost part of the bridge into position (if not, maybe just the outermost and the middle) and just dive onto it to get inside. Clearly this would be rather cheap, so I'm wondering if it's possible, and if not, what the game does to stop you.

Comment: Some Hylians just want to see the world burn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, you can't. The bridges move if they aren't lined up right and if you fly, so...

I should say that I did this before I understood what the puzzle was, it was really annoying...

Comment: Party pooper :)

Comment: So you're saying that getting on your bird will reset the puzzle if it's not complete?

Comment: @Toomai: Yep. That's exactly correct.

Answer (score 0):

The only way into the Isle of Songs requires the bridge. You have to figure out a way to line up each section. If only there was something you could use to block certain sections to get things to line up…

Fortunately, you only have to do this once. It's also not nearly as hard as the Temple of Time guardian puzzle or beating that dirty, dirty, cheating Yeta at snowboarding in *Twilight Princess*. I still have nightmares about her accursed laugh.

Comment: This answer appears to be answering "How do I solve this?", not "Is it possible to skip solving it?". I already know the solution; I'm wondering what the game does if you try to dodge the solution.